# What Windows message is sent to repaint a partially occluded window?

Tags: winapi, windows-xp, messaging, paint

I know that WM_PAINT tells a window that it needs to repaint itself entirely, but apparently that's not the message that gets sent when it's been covered partially and then the window that was in front of it is no longer in the way and it needs to repaint the dirty portion.  Does anyone know what message is sent in this case?

EDIT: Found the problem:

The issue involved a Delphi control I wrote to embed a [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org) rendering surface on a Delphi form.  SDL has an API to build its renderer on another window's HWND, and it marks it as a "foreign window".

SDL usually handles `WM_PAINT` internally, so I ended up having to add some code to SDL's WindowProc to forward the message on to the external WindowProc if it's a foreign window.  That was working sometimes, but it turns out there was a glitch that was stripping the foreign window flag from the window's data structure, so it was swallowing the message instead of passing it on to my app.  Once I fixed that, I started getting the `WM_PAINT` messages all the time.

Comment: All of the 5 answers are correct: WM_PAINT is *the* message that gets send when part - or all - of your client area needs to be repainted. On newer versions of Windows it is not sent as often as it used to be because Windows is caching the desktop far more aggressively in order to achieve the layered window and glass window visual effects - windows is painting from internal bitmaps NOT sending any kind of message at all in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you say it's apparently not? [`WM_PAINT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/wm-paint) should be called for partial redraws (the updated rect is returned by [`BeginPaint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-beginpaint) or [`GetUpdateRect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getupdaterect)). If it doesn't appear to be getting called, there may be a bug elsewhere in your app that's preventing it. What are you seeing that leads you to believe that it's not working?

Comment: Because I've got a Delphi component with a method to handle WM_PAINT, but it's not getting called for partial redraws. I can only conclude, then, that no WM_PAINT is being sent.  Either that, or something's very wrong somewhere along the line, because I *am* getting it just fine for full paints.

Comment: What are you doing to invoke a partial redraw (and what OS?)

Comment: I'm only seeing this on XP, since Vista stores the appearance of each form in its own buffer before drawing them to the screen.  What I'm doing is opening another window, which shows up in front of the form I'm using, and then bringing my form back to the foreground.  Everything gets repainted properly except the one component, which is never getting a WM_PAINT message, and I'm trying to figure out what's going on and why.

Answer (score 1):

`WM_PAINT` is sent to indicate that some portion (including the entirity) of the window needs to be repainted.

Call [GetUpdateRect()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144943(VS.85).aspx) to get a rectangle that bounds the region to be updated.  This information is also included in the PAINTSTRUCT (as the rcPaint field) passed to [BeginPaint()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183362(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty certain the Win32 API uses `WM_PAINT` even for partial repaints. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145213%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> The `WM_PAINT` message is sent when the system or another application makes a request to paint *a portion* of an application's window. *[My italics].*

That link has the full detail on `WM_PAINT` but if, as you say, the WM_PAINT message is *not* being sent for partial redraws, the [Spy++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa315486%28VS.60%29.aspx) is the tool you need to find out for sure.

Answer (score 0):

The BeginPaint() function returns the rect that requires validation in its 2nd parameter: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183362(VS.85).aspx

```
case WM_PAINT:
{
PAINTSTRUCT psPaint;
HDC hdc = BeginPaint( hwnd, &psPaint );
// psPaint.rcPaint contains invalidated area
EndPaint (hwnd, &psPaint);
}
return 0;
```

Look at psPaint.rcPaint : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162768(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`WM_PRINTCLIENT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145217%28VS.85%29.aspx).  There are some circumstances when `WM_PAINT` is not sent and a `WM_PRINTCLIENT` message is sent instead. ([`AnimateWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632669%28VS.85%29.aspx) for example.)